# How to add tooltip on input field by using zurb foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

I want to add a tooltip at bottom of input area.
So I wrote like this.

```
<div class="row collapse">
  <div class="small-9 columns">
    <span data-tooltip class="has-tip" title="Tooltip">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name">
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="small-3 columns">
    <a href="#" class="button prefix">Action</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But tooltip is appeared not at bottom of input field, but over the field.
How can I show tooltip bottom of input area correctly?

Comment: did you get this figured out yet? Trying to find the answer also.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<div class="row collapse">
  <div class="small-9 columns">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name" data-tooltip class="has-tip" title="Tooltip">
  </div>
  <div class="small-3 columns">
    <a href="#" class="button prefix">Action</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you could place the tip in the `<div class="small-9 columns">`

Answer (score 0):

This java-script gives the same effect as foundation5 tooltip, but for form elments without using the tooltip plugin.

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name" data-tooltip title="This is the tip" />
```

Javascript:

```
inputToolTip: function() {
  var _fadeSpeed = 400;
  $("input[data-tooltip],textarea[data-tooltip]").each(function(k, input) {
    var $input = $(input);
    var _tiptext = $input.attr('title');
    console.log($input);
    var $tip = $('<div class="tip-place"><span class="tooltip tip-bottom tip-me">' + 
                  _tiptext + '<span class="nub"></span></span></div>').hide();
    $input.after($tip);
    $input.focus(function() {
      $tip.fadeIn(_fadeSpeed);
      $input.attr('title','');
    }).blur(function() {
      $input.attr('title',_tiptext);
      $tip.fadeOut(_fadeSpeed);
    });
    $input.removeAttr('data-tooltip');
  })
};
inputToolTip(); // You will need to call this again, after adding a form via ajax, etc.
```

And finally some CSS Code

```
.tooltip.tip-me { 
  left: 1em
  display: block
  top: -1em
  position: relative
}
.tip-place {
  height: 0
}
```